# Can't fetch data from service angular2

Tags: angular, subscribe

My service:

```
private dataObs = new Subject<Employee>();
getData():Observable<Employee>{
     return  this.dataObs.asObservable();
}
setData(data: Employee) {
    this.dataObs.next(data);
}
```

My parent component looks like this:

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.updateData(this.temp)
}
updateData(value: Employee) {
   this.parentData.setData(value)
}
```

My child component to access the updated data:

```
constructor(private parentData:GetParentData){
    setTimeout(this.printData(),200)
}
printData(){
    this.parentData.getData().subscribe(data=>console.log("Display Data:" , data))
}
```

I'm expecting is the value from service, which i'm not able to get.
The console.log in the service() is not executing..

Comment: We need more info. Where do you provide this service? Also please include the constructor and annotations of these classes.

Comment: If it is also possible to include a [plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5?p=catalogue) that would help too!

Comment: When `setData` method got called.. does `child component` was loaded in DOM tree?